# Nuxt.js: Preload fonts and other assets, configured by nuxt.config.js

Tags: performance, webpack, nuxt.js

I'd like to preload fonts (and web worker JS-files). Fonts are located in the `static/fonts`-folder. I've got this in the nuxt.config.js, but it doesn't seem to work. No errors. The `<link>`-element is not added to `<head>`.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
        if (type === 'font') return file.includes('.woff2');
        return ['script', 'style'].includes(type);
      }
    },
  }
  // ..
}
```

However, I am able to add the fonts manually. And they are preloaded just fine.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  head: {
    link: [
      {
        rel: "preload",
        href: "/fonts/my-font.woff2",
        crossorigin: "anonymous",
        as: "font",
        type: "font/woff2"
      },
    ]
  }
  // ...
}
```

Using Nuxt v. 2.14.7

Sources:

- https://ssr.vuejs.org/api/#shouldpreload
- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-render#bundlerenderer

Answer (score 1):

I've personally always just added my tweaks to `<head>` into the nuxt.config.js `head` section, which parallels what you do in a page.  There might be a more clever programmatic way to do it, but mine seems to work.  If you use `hid` you can override the individual values local to a page as well.

Hopefully it helps as a quickie solution.
`nuxt.config.js` follows

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    head: {
        htmlAttrs: {
          lang: 'en'
        },
        title: 'My Site',
        meta: [
          { charset: 'utf-8' },
          { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
          {
            name: 'google-site-verification',
            content: 'yup-some-key-here'
          },
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: 'Wonderous personal stuff'
          },
          {
            hid: 'og:image',
            property: 'og:image',
            content: 'https://y.yarn.co/451fe9c2-9ac8-415a-8499-f24e157f128a_thumb.jpg'
          }
        ],
        link: [
          { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
          { rel: 'preconnect', href: 'https://www.google-analytics.com' },
          {
            rel: 'preload',
            href: '/fonts/didact-gothic-v13-latin-regular.woff2',
            as: 'font',
            type: 'font/woff2',
            crossorigin: true
          }
        ]
    }
}
```