# Preloading fonts with <link> tag in Nuxt.js app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

To preload fonts, I'm trying to add a `<link>` tag to my [`app.html` file in Nuxt 2.15](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#document-apphtml). The problem is that I don't know how to access my `/assets/fonts` folder.

```vue
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
    <link rel="preload" href="~/assets/fonts/SoDoSans-Regular.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I access that `/assets/` folder from within `app.html`? This gives me 404 errors because `localhost:xxxx/~/assets/fonts/` folder doesn't exist. I've tried using `require()` but that doesn't work either. It just adds it as part of the string.

I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855375/nuxt-js-preload-fonts-and-other-assets-configured-by-nuxt-config-js) suggests modifying `nuxt.config.js`, but I need to do it with a `<link>` tag from `app.html`

Comment: The tilde (~) symbol is used to reference the project root within the context of a nuxt project. However, that feature is something that gets interpreted at build time and I believe that interpretation won't happen in this context because your in the html file and whatever you pass into the `href` property is treated as a true string here. Try using traditional relative paths here or loading your font through the configuration file: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-head

Comment: @JasonGross Thanks, but the tilde is not really the issue… I’ve tried everything: `/assets, ./assets, assets, ~/assets…` the problem is that the string never gets processed by Nuxt so it will never get transformed too the true assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can put you font file under static folder with Nuxt 2

- https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/directory-structure/static/

---

first, put your font file in `/static` folder in your project

then you can use relative path in your `<link>` href

```
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/SoDoSans-Regular.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to stackoverflow ! While your answer is highly appreciated, it might be unclear. Can you please edit it to add details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. i.e. show how using the static folder is the way to go?

Comment: @SalimMahboubi ok, I will add more details about how using the static folder